# Chrome DevTools - exact size of transferred data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know the size of transferred data for a website (including ajax data) in KB.

In Chrome DevTools, when the size is larger than 1 MB, it switches from KB to MB, so I loose precision. I want to know the size in KB, but I can't find that information anywhere. Does anybody have an idea how to get that information in Chromium?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the server sends back a `Content-Length` header in the Response Headers, you can view the size of the data, in bytes, that is sent to the client in the Network tab as per below.

[image: Content-Length Header]

If there is no `Content-Length` header returned, you can look at the HTTP Archive (HAR) for the transfer size (discussed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444587)). Right click on the Source and select 'Copy all as HAR'. Paste this into a text editor and you will see the full response object. Search for the 'Request URL' you are looking for, and you should see a `_transferSize` property with a corresponding value in bytes within the Response section.

[image: HAR]

Answer (score 1):

[image: mouse on]

Place the mouse on the specific number, you can see the data accurate to the byte.

1KB = 1024B

want to know the size of transferred data for a website (including ajax data) in KB.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly unrelated but on macOS, I found in Safari you can view the total number of bytes sent and received and their size after decompression. To view this go to the `Network` tab, click on an entry, and then click on `Sizes`.

[image]